# Is there a standard for keeping extra info about a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, metadata

My task involves reading from a constantly updated MySQL table created with:

```
CREATE TABLE mailing (
    addr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

(no date_created fields or anything, kind of arbitrary, I know, but this is what I am given)

This table is supposed to hold millions of email addresses, and more will be added daily.

I am supposed to count the daily growth from the last 30 days of all the domains in this table in a separate one, which I create with:

```
CREATE TABLE domain_count (
    domain VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    total_count INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    count_1 INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    count_2 INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ...
    count_30 INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

If say, on day 1 mailing table contains 10 addresses from a single domain, and on day 2 it contains 15 addresses, then I'd like for domain_count.count_1 = 10 and domain_count.count_2 = 5

To that end, I need to keep track of 2 things: one is the total number of addresses in the mailing table as of yesterday (so for day 2 I should have "10" stored somewhere, and for day 3, I should have "15" stored somewhere; with this I can resume searching from the 11th/16th column of the mailing table). The other is the latest count_# value since I need to know to insert into count_2 on day 2 (and loop around back to count_1 on day 31).

I can store these values in a separate file easily, but it feels really messy doing something like that. Is there a MySQL query that would let me associate those values with the tables themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard for what you describe, no.

There's [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html), which *is* part of the SQL standard.  The [TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) table has a column `TABLE_ROWS`, but this only shows the *current* number of rows.

To do what you describe, I'd make another conventional table based on the TABLES table, add a TIMESTAMP column, and periodically copy rows from the I_S table to my own.

```
CREATE TABLE mydatabase.TABLES like INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

ALTER TABLE mydatabase.TABLES ADD COLUMN updated_at TIMESTAMP;

/* once per day do the following: */    
INSERT INTO mydatabase.TABLES 
 SELECT *, NOW() FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE (table_schema, table_name) = ('mydatabase', 'mytable');
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question: such aggregation and denormalisation of your data for reporting is something that would typically be covered by a [data warehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) rather than by the DBMS.

To help with your problem, a neater structure might be the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `domain_count` (
    `domain` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `count` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

It's still separating an aggregation of the data from the data itself, but you might find the structure easier to query for your requirements. You can use [date range](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) / [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operators to get the ranges that you're interested in, and SUM the counts or use GROUP BY to group by domain, month etc.